# Using curl in C++ to get page that changes after sometime

Tags: c++, curl, web-crawler, libcurl

I was trying to make a webscraper in C++ (I know I could use some other language but I'm just trying to learn). There's a webpage I'm trying to get the html code to but the page changes after a second or two with the links I want. How do I make the program wait until sometime to return the html?

Edit: I want to make a curl call once and then wait some time and then do another curl call to the same webpage after some time. (Not open the link again as it would give the same page)

Comment: Can you describe the question a bit more? Do you want to make a curl call every X seconds for e.g. or do you want to make a curl call (thereby getting results) and then wait for X seconds before making another call?

Comment: @aliak Oh okay I meant that I want to make a curl call after X seconds. Not repeatedly. Thanks

Comment: You can sleep for 2 seconds with `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo and then do I do another curl_easy_perform()?

Comment: @друг Perhaps. I'm not sure what "_Not open the link again as it would give the same page_" means. I was just giving a hint of how to do `X` and `Y` with a 2 second delay between the events.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I meant that when you open the link in a browser, the HTML code changes after certain seconds, revealing a link. But if I open the link again after X seconds in the browser, it still waits X seconds before revealing the link. So I want to make a curl call and wait a certain time before it returns with the results.

Comment: @друг It sounds like some javascript code needs to be executed or that it redirects to a different page after some time. I think you need to look at the first document you download to be able to figure out what makes the code change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options:

1. investigate the site and figure out how the javascript code is changing the page, then replicate that in C++ (either by hard-coding a URL or parsing parts of the page),
2. embed a full browser engine that understands JavaScript and click the link after it changes, or
3. abandon C++ and use a dedicated scraping tool like CasperJS or Scrapy or wring or ...

I would inspect the page and see if you can make option 1 work, but option 3 is by far the easiest approach.

Comment: The thing is that I have done it in dedicated scraping tools. I just wanted to try doing it in C++

Comment: Then you will have to investigate the page. Curl by itself will not be enough.

Comment: I found the javascript that runs. It calls to an api with a JSON file with the links. Now have to parse JSON. Thanks for the suggestion though, it really helped